# SOAP Binding type does not have impact on the resulting WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I tried the sample code from mkyong site and played around with combination of parameters.
I tried changing the javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL to javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use.ENCODED for an RPC style service interface.

```
    package com.mkyong.ws;

    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;
    import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle;

    //Service Endpoint Interface
    @WebService
    @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.ENCODED, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
    public interface HelloWorld{

        @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);

    }
```

The only change was instead of `use = Use.LITERAL` now I have `use = Use.ENCODED`.
However the resulting WSDL does not seem to change at all.

The WSDL created in both cases still shows the `<soap:body>` use property as "literal".

```
<soap:body use="literal"
```

Is there a mistake somewhere in my declaration of the interface?

```
<binding name="HelloWorldImplPortBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"></soap:binding>
    <operation name="getHelloWorldAsString">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/"></soap:body>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://ws.mkyong.com/"></soap:body>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Is this correct? Should I not be expecting `use="Encoded"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In few of the WS implementation Use.ENCODED is not implemented.
This may be one of the reason why use are getting the same WSDL.
rpc/encoded wsdls are not supported in JAXWS 2.0.
rpc/encoded is also not supported in JAXWS 2.2.
Please refer the below link for the same.
https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.1/docs/annotations.html.

Comment: I am using Java 1.7.0_25 and using the stock JAX-WS support to create these simple classes. Any idea if this could be an issue?

Comment: Java 7 includes JAX-WS 2.2. I am not sure Use.ENCODED is supported by this version or not but in JAX-WS 2.0 it was not.

Comment: RPC/ENCODED is not supported by JAX-WS 2.2. Please refer to the link below. https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.1/docs/annotations.html. I think that answers you question. If yes, please accept the answer